# Better way to manage storyboards under git?

Tags: ios, git, storyboard

I have a project that my developers work on, and the tasks are divided so that one person does most of the business logic, and two developers do front-end, divided into tasks.

Now we are having the problem that the 2 front-end developers are having conflicts on their storyboards. The most problems occur when one developer fixes a problem, and decides to fix it everywhere, thus going into the other's view controllers. Also, storyboards in general cause updates to frames getting updated just a little bit and views suddenly being misplaced.

We have code review so the front-end developers check each others code, so this creates another problem, being the delay between a pull request and it being merged into the master. Thus the thing that he was working on can't be immediately used again for a new task (because a new task = a new branch).

Is there a better way to work with storyboards and git?

Comment: Hi. Didn't use the single storyboard with all scenes in your project. Need to break it up into several parts grouped by logical content (e.g. `Managing Profile Scene`, `Managing Credit Cards Scene` and etc.). Each scene is a single storyboard.

Comment: Talk about it. When it happens make it a single commit with nothing else (or minimal other changes) in it. Expedite the review process. If it happens frequently, look at why and resolve that root cause. Generally storyboards are much better than they were, though the frame changes are incredibly irritating...

Comment: @Wain yes those frame changes, I have no clue. The developers have the exact same macbook, same year, same specs. They all have the latest version of xcode and still inconsistencies in storyboards...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should look into Storyboard references - this will reduce the conflicts you will have.

But you cannot have 2 people working on the same storyboard without conflicting (sometimes you might get away with it)

**iOS 8+ Compatability**

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=215

---

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/refactoring-with-storyboard-references.html

It has always been possible to split a large user interface into several Storyboards. The disadvantage was that you could not then create segues in Interface Builder between the different Storyboards. Instead you needed to wire up target-action connections in the Storyboard of the presenting view controller and use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` to get the destination view controller to present.

Storyboard references introduced with Xcode 7 give you a way to split a large storyboard and still create the segues between scenes in Interface Builder.

### Refactoring a Large Storyboard

To show how to use Storyboard references consider the following Storyboard for a simple iPhone app using a tab bar controller.

[image: large_storyboard]

The first “news” tab contains a split view controller with the usual table view based master-detail segues. The second “settings” tab has a static table view with segues to three other view controllers.

I also have an iPad version of the Storyboard with the Settings views presented in a popover from a button on the toolbar. We can avoid duplicating those scenes in the iPad Storyboard by first refactoring them into a separate Storyboard file:

- Select the scenes to be refactored - in this case the root navigation controller, the Settings table view controller and the three child view controllers.
- From the Editor menu select Refactor to Storyboard and when prompted enter the name of the new Storyboard (I used Settings) and save it.
- Interface Builder will switch to show you the newly created Storyboard which should contain the previously selected Settings scenes and segues.
- If you switch back to the main Storyboard you will see that the Settings scenes have been replaced with a placeholder representing the Storyboard reference:

[image: storyboard_reference]

Unfortunately the tab bar item for the Settings has lost its title and icon. I am not sure if that is a bug or a feature (a radar will follow). For now I manually add them back in the main Storyboard.

### Adding a Reference to a Storyboard

To make use of the new Settings Storyboard drag a Storyboard reference from the object library into the iPad Storyboard:

[image: reference]

Use the attributes inspector to set the Storyboard name and identifier of the navigation controller in the Settings Storyboard:

[image: reference]

Once you have a Storyboard reference you can use it as the target of a segue. So for example I can create a popover segue from a bar button item to the Settings Storyboard reference:

[image: reference]

### Room For Improvement

A disadvantage with this approach to Storyboard references is that you can no longer view the whole user interface on a single screen. I was hoping that Interface Builder would automatically resolve the references to show the contents of each of the Storyboards when looking at the main Storyboard. Maybe that will come in Xcode 8?

One other negative if you refactor a localised Storyboard is that you need to remember to manually copy the localisation strings for the new Storyboard. Xcode does not currently manage that for you.

Update 27 August 2015: I should also mention if you want to maintain backward compatibility with iOS 8 you cannot use storyboard references as the target of a relationship segue. For example, you cannot embed a storyboard reference in a tab bar controller or make it the root of a navigation controller on iOS 8.